# How do I display an Outlook Calendar that hasn't been shared with me?

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook

I'm using the following code:

```
var msOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
var session = msOutlook.Session;
var recipient = session.CreateRecipient(textBox1.Text);
var folder = session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
folder.Display();
```

And this works fine for a calendar that's been explicitly shared with me, but not for anyone else's.

However - if I go into Outlook, open my calendar, and then click on "Open Calendar" and select someone else's calendar then I can see all of the entries, even if it isn't explicitly shared.

Is there any way to programmatically get Outlook to display this screen?

Comment: Do you mean the address book window when you click the 'Name" button?

Comment: I mean that I open the Calendar view, then click "Open Calendar" on the toolbar, then "From Address Book" and select someone.

Comment: Same window you get if you hit Ctrl+Shift+B, right?

Comment: That's the picker, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You display the Outlook address book using SelectNamesDialog. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176400(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: It's not the Address Book I want.  It's their Calendar.  The one you get in Outlook 2010 if you open the Calendar view and then click "Open Calendar" and select someone from the address book.

Comment: GetSharedDefaultFolder is what you need. If the Calendar folder is not shared, the best you can do is request the free/busy information using Recipient.FreeBusy.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like Outlook can do things itself that you can't do programmatically!